# Why is the standard-guaranteed range for Int in Haskell exactly [-2^29; 2^29)?

Tags: haskell

Why is the range so specific? Why not 29-bits wide or 32 bits-wide, why 30?

What is the reasoning? The standard([1](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#dx13-135009)) doesn't seem to give it

Comment: If I recall correctly, back in the days *Yale Haskell* used two bits for "tagging", to avoid "boxing" integers, for example to mark that an `Int` is unevaluated. GHC does not use that as far as I know, but it is possible thus to implement your own haskell interpreter/compiler/... and make use of this.

Comment: I thought about it, but felt like that would probably significantly slow down arithmetic operations, to keep the bit untouched. However it makes sense. Thanks for the answer! Do you wish to answer it the ordinary way? So that I have a way to mark it as answered

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22338778/1446609

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up asking about this mystery on the [Haskell Discourse forum](https://discourse.haskell.org/t/where-are-the-two-missing-bits-from-int/7962) where multiple theories were presented, until one user was able to confirm that in all likelyhood it indeed was because of Yale Haskell (as  [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73106581/why-is-the-standard-guaranteed-range-for-int-in-haskell-exactly-229-229#comment129117093_73106581) already speculated).

Yale Haskell compiles Haskell programs down to Common Lisp programs. (Specifically, Yale Haskell was intended to run on Lucid Common Lisp, CMU Common Lisp (CMUCL), or Armed Bear Common Lisp (AKCL)). Lisp, being (unlike Haskell) a fully dynamically typed programming language needs to retain all type information at runtime.

The approach taken by CMUCL was to use the three lower bits as tag [1, 2] on all runtime values for this type information.
Two bit patterns were reserved for 'even' and 'odd' small integers (`fixnum`s), to give a 30-bit range.

So if a Haskell program was compiled down to a Common Lisp program and the intention was to re-use the Lisp `fixnum` for Haskell's `Int`s, the effective range of them would only be 30 bits, in other words the `[-2^29..2^29-1]` range.

---

None of this is really important any more in the modern era, for the following reasons:

- Yale Haskell has been discontinued in ca. 1995 [3]. GHC Haskell, which compiles down to machine code rather than Lisp, is able to use the full 32-bit/64-bit range for `Int`.
- CMU Common Lisp is still around and still 32-bit only. But [it seems like it has been replaced in big part](https://lisp-lang.org/wiki/article/implementations) in the Common Lisp community by [Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL)](http://sbcl.org/) which [forked from it in 1999](http://sbcl.org/history.html). SBCL uses a different internal representation for `fixnum`s.
- Modern hardware has very different constraints: Compact memory usage is less important than inlining arithmetic and pleasing the branch predictor. For instance, CMUCL's tagging approach is incompatible with IEEE floating point numbers, which is probably why other techniques are used nowadays.

---

1. [CMU internal docs about tagging](https://cmucl.org/docs/internals/html/Tagging.html)
2. [CMU internal docs about about Fixnum specifically](https://cmucl.org/docs/internals/html/Fixnums.html)
3. [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With Class](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/history.pdf?from=https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/history-of-haskell/history.pdf&type=exact)